# javascript split string at at two different indexes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a credit card # for amex I.E. **371449635398431** that I'd like to split up into 3 parts **3714 496353 98431** - Is there an easy way to split a string up by predefined indexes (in this case 4 & 10), possibly with a simple regex function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really see the need for regular expressions here. If you know the indexes you need to split on, you can just do this:

```
var input = '371449635398431'
var part1 = input.substr(0, 4);
var part2 = input.substr(4, 6);
var part3 = input.substr(10);
```

But if a regular expression is a must, you can do this:

```
var input = '371449635398431'
var match = /^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})$/.exec(input);
var part1 = match[1];
var part2 = match[2];
var part3 = match[3];
```

---

To insert spaces between each part you can do this:

```
var match = input.substr(0, 4) + ' ' + input.substr(4, 6) + ' ' + input.substr(10);
```

Or this:

```
var match = [ input.substr(0, 4), input.substr(4, 6), input.substr(10) ].join(' ');
```

Or this (inspired by [*Arun P Johny*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758531/1715579)):

```
var match = /^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})$/.exec(input).slice(1).join(' ');
```

Or this:

```
var match = input.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})$/, '$1 $2 $3');
```

Comment: Is there any fallbacks to doing it the regex way? If the full amount of numbers are not listed, will it fail (as I see it looks for 4 then 6 then 5). Unfortunately I know very little about regex. How is it different having the ^ and $ in it compared to without? (Also: I was just trying to add spaces if the number is copy/pasted into the field and felt like it should be done on 1 line.)

Comment: Oh, also - is there any way to not grab the original full text? so I can just do a join(' ')? It seems a little redundant having to use the  "splice(1)" as mentioned in Arun's answer.

Comment: The main problem is performance. Regex will be slower than direct manipulation. `^` and `$` are start and end anchors, repsectively. It means that `match` will be an empty array if there are any leading / trailing characters. The regex will also return an empty array if there are not enough characters or if there are characters other than digits. Using `match.splice(1).join(' ')` (or `slice(1)`) is a good solution for this.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Performance is rarely a problem unless trying to build a game or something. I think simple, readable code is more important, unless the OP happens to be processing thousands of credit card numbers every second.

Comment: @tjameson Yes, very true. There's nothing wrong with any of these approaches (and someone could probably suggest another equally valid one). The regex solution is perfectly reasonable, but a lot of times I see regular expression used where direct string manipulation is more simple and readable. And of course, [there's this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var array = '371449635398431'.match(/(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})/).splice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I improve [p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758526/860099) answer by using slice instead substr (input string in s)

```
[s.slice(0,4), s.slice(4,10), s.slice(10)]
```

```js
let s="371449635398431"; 
let a=[s.slice(0,4), s.slice(4,10), s.slice(10)]

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I simplified regex used in answers [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758531/860099) and [p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758526/860099)

```
'371449635398431'.match(/(.{4})(.{6})(.{5})/).splice(1)
```

```js
var a = '371449635398431'.match(/(.{4})(.{6})(.{5})/).splice(1);

console.log(a);
```