# Store First & Second Character value in two different veritable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to store First & Second character of value in two different variable `id` with `ccMain`.Using jquery or Javascript.

Here is the html code I have to set up the environment:

```
<span id="ccMain">GM</span>
```

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: This question is [asking for a solution without attempting to show any work](https://can-i-haz.codes/).  Please provide some code to help us work with you to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript split string at at two different indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758512/javascript-split-string-at-at-two-different-indexes)

Comment: opps! even tell me, i m some confuse.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain javascript, you can use the "substring" method of a string object to retrieve specific characters.  Please see [MDN String::substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
var main = document.getElementById("ccMain");
var text = main.innerText;
console.log("First Letter: " + text.substring(0,1));
console.log("Second Letter: " + text.substring(1,2));
```

```html
<div id="ccMain">Simple Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need first and second characters you could use indexs as `0` and `1` to get first and second values.

```js
var str = $('#ccMain').text();
var first = str[0];
var second = str[1];
console.log(first," ", second)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ccMain">GM</span>
```